# What is the origin of Left and Right in politics

Tags: political-philosophy, terminology, definitions, politics

I've read many times that left and right in politics come from the French Revolution.

But reading the [Dao De Jing, chapter 31](http://ctext.org/dao-de-jing#n11622), it looks a very similar definition.

The left is the place of the "second commander", the "ordinary", the "folk", the "festivities".

The right is the place of "war", "first commander" closer to the king, the "mourning" and elaborate/artificial/sad rituals of the noble families.

Other translations get to an even closer resemblance.

So, is this just a coincidence? Or perhaps both sources (Chinese and French) have drank from the same spring? Where exactly the concepts of left and right in politics were first used in a way similar to those we use today?

Comment: I wonder if this wasn't a question more appropriate for either Politics.SE or History.SE...

Comment: This might be purely coincidental, but to add to the fun: In Islam, the right side is the "good" side, and the left side is the "sinful" side.

Comment: I think this would be better off on the politics site. Either way, brilliant question.

Comment: Apparently 90% of the world is right-handed.  Chinese and French.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking I expect it would come back as political theory/philosophy.

Comment: Similar question on the politics site though: http://politics.stackexchange.com/q/13547

Comment: @ChrisDegnen: Nope, as it seems it is a fact of politics of France during the years of and following 'La Grande Révolution'. Therefore, it is totally accidental that these notions found their way into ordinary language, as they were handy abbreviations for certain political views. There is nothing philosophical there. Regarding the Dao, I find it quite obvious that "right" here stands for strength, rigour, and the hand that is used for the sword whereas left stands for softness, possibly art and communication. It has nothing to do with politics in particular.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking That the French loyalists would be placed on the 'honoured' right seems quite plausible.  That there is a difference between authoritarian loyalists and libertarians is perfectly in the domain of group psychology and [political theory/philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_philosophy).

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking However Wikipedia does go on to say "Political philosophy is considered by some to be a sub-discipline of political science; however, the name generally attributed to this form of political enquiry is political theory, a discipline which has a closer methodology to the theoretical fields in the social sciences (like economic theory) than to philosophical argumentation (like that of moral philosophy or aesthetics)."

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking I think the question fits here and there as well, since there's an overlap. And I'm part of this forum, not politics, so please let the question stay here. About the Dao translation, compare "The superior man ordinarily considers the left hand the most honourable place" with "Someone noble, when at home, value the left". Anyway, the question remains: is there any link between the two? If so, what is it?

Comment: 'He is seated at the right hand of the Father' is embedded in the Nicene creed, so the idea of placing those favored by authorities to their right seems to go back much farther than the French Revolution in the West.

Comment: @Rodrigo So in Rome the right is the honoured side while in China the left is the honoured side.  Seems to indicate no link.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen in Rome the right is honoured by the "Father", which is similar to the "King". So they all agree up to now.

Comment: @Rodrigo Above you wrote "The superior man ordinarily considers the left hand the most honourable place" so that's opposite to Rome where you say "the right is honoured".

Comment: @ChrisDegnen "ordinarily" comes from 居, which in other translations means "when at home", as opposed to "when serving the king at war" - at war he values the right. Is this distinction (left=home=popular, right=king) it's similar to France and Rome. Keep in mind that James Legge is one of the first translations, and it's not the best available.

Answer (score 3):

Society naturally divides into authoritarians and liberals.  The reason is, everyone starts out as authoritarian, following instruction from parents and teachers.  (Authoritarian does not mean being bossy or socially dominant (SD); it means following authority.)

Later in life, upon entering adulthood, some people self-actualise, individuate, start thinking more independently, become free-thinkers.  (The process is a difficult wrench because the automatic follow-the-leader instincts and peer pressure have to be wrestled with.)

People who are free-thinkers tend to let others get on with their own thing: a generally [liberal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberalism) attitude.  Authoritarians generally stick to their chosen authority base.

[Professor Bob Altemeyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Altemeyer) devised a psychological test to measure right-wing authoritarianism (RWA),.  He managed to get US politicians to take the test, the results from which are shown below, (and [here](http://members.shaw.ca/jeanaltemeyer/drbob/TheAuthoritarians.pdf), page 201).  The scoring showed that the right-wing tended to cluster to their authority-bound attitudes while the left were more distributed across the spectrum, following their own ideas, however varied they were.

[image]

Autoritarian versus liberal is not the only division in politics.  There is also an economic dimension. [The Political Compass](https://www.politicalcompass.org/) is a good site for finding out about this.

https://www.politicalcompass.org/analysis2

[image]

[image]

The Political Compass puts the terms left and right on the economic axis saying:

> Our essential point is that Left and Right, although far from obsolete, are essentially a measure of economics.

However, in its origin, and still to a large extent today, I would say, left and right relate to the social authoritarian-liberal spectrum.  In the French Revolution the right were the authority loyalists and the left were the ones with new ideas.  There was also a respective dimension of wealth preservation and wealth redistribution though.

[Wikipedia: Left-right politics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left%E2%80%93right_politics#History_of_the_terms)

> The terms "left" and "right" appeared during the French Revolution of
>   1789 when members of the National Assembly divided into supporters of
>   the king to the president's right and supporters of the revolution to
>   his left.

Presumably the rebels were placed on the establishment's left side, the "sinister" ([*sinistro*](http://wordinfo.info/unit/3777/s:and)) side, for nuanced effect, while the authoritarian loyalists were on the honoured right.

By contrast, in reference to the Tâo Te Ching, [Chapter 31](http://www.sacred-texts.com/tao/mt/mt34.htm), C. Spurgeon Medhurst (trans.) writes:

> The references to the right and the left will be understood when it is
>   remembered that in China the left is the seat of honor, the right the
>   lower and inferior seat.

So in China the esteem of left and right is opposite to that in the Roman and Western world, indicating no common source.

Comment: I think this would be better off on the politics site. Either way, brilliant question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Chris. I knew about the Political Compass, but what I'm interested here is in the impressive relation between the French and Old Chinese Left/Right terms. As you and others have noted, it may have its origin in the biological dominance of right-handedness. But is this all there is to it?

Comment: @Rodrigo: if that's what you're interested in you should say so explicitly. it's not what you asked originally.

Comment: @mobileink It's in the end of my question: "is this just a coincidence? Or perhaps both sources (Chinese and French) have drank from the same spring?" Although Chris' answer is interesting, it didn't answer the origin of the concepts (only again the French). But if the Chinese used a similar concept 2500 years ago, then the mystery remains.

Comment: @Rodrigo Apparently it follows the opposite pattern in Taoism.  The notes to [Chapter 31](http://www.sacred-texts.com/tao/mt/mt34.htm) say: "in China the left is the seat of honor, the right the lower and inferior seat."

Comment: @ChrisDegnen Where did you read those notes? In ctext.org I only found the notes in Chinese, and from what I could understand, they are associating the left (左) with humble, inferior, vulgar (卑), with Yang (陽) and with the absence of killing (不專殺也); and the right (右) with senior, honor (尊), with Yin (陰) and with the act of killing (專主殺也). Furthermore, the english translation goes "The second in command of the army has his place on the left; the general commanding in chief has his on the right". This looks very similar with the French Revolution.

Comment: @Rodrigo - I included a link. It is http://www.sacred-texts.com/tao/mt/mt34.htm

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice at first. But as the text says: at home people value the left. At war they value the right. Like the revolutionary in France value the left (the people), those close to the king value the right. It looks similar to me. Another thing: I never heard about C. Spurgeon Medhurst before, but seeing his site it's obvious that he have studied many different cultures. But in translating the chapter 31 he made a mistake: 君子 is a noble person (in England, barons, viscounts, earls, marquesses and dukes), not the Taoist Sage (which is usually represented by 聖人, sometimes 真人). But...

Comment: ...reading his third paragraph, it occurred to me that "The Second Officer is placed on the left, but the Commander-in-Chief is placed on the right" BECAUSE "When affairs are felicitous the left is honored, but when they are inauspicious the right is honored". Now your point makes sense to me -- "in China the left is the seat of honor, the right the lower and inferior seat." But this looks a popular view, and the king view might be just the opposite. Similar to when USA changed the universal "red(left)/blue(right)" for "red(right)/blue(left)" around the 2000s.

Comment: @Rodrigo Nevertheless the Chinese distinction seems a lot more nuanced and different from the more basic Roman/Western one described here: [http://wordinfo.info/unit/3777](http://wordinfo.info/unit/3777/s:and). I wasn't aware the [US political colours reversed in 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_states_and_blue_states) but it is universal that the political Right is synonymous with the authoritarian end of the political spectrum.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen Thanks for the links! Now, if right meant authoritarian, there would be no need for a Political Compass at all! About right/left, I think it stems from our biology, where 90% of people is right-handed. So, in 90% of people the right hand is more dextrous, thus used in war. At home, people want to forget war, so they "value the left hand". Maybe that's why the political left came to mean "defend the people's values" and political right "defend the king's values". Only a king would wage war, and only he is worried about its results. For the people, they'll always be paying taxes...

Comment: @Rodrigo It goes to show that one should specify whether one means the economic left & right or the social left & right.  However, looking at the distribution in the 2008 US Election at https://www.politicalcompass.org/uselection2008 most of the politicians are left or right in *both* economic and social dimensions at the same time. Only Mike Gravel is economic-right and social-left.

Comment: OK, Mike Gravel is the "exception confirming the rule", and it makes sense indeed.

Comment: Figure 5.1 is amazing! Wonder if anyone ever graphed the Average RWA versus Average Latitude, to try to see the effects of the North-South division during the "American Civil War" (1861-1865).

Answer (score 1):

"Left" and "right" as political concepts are from the 18th Century, and the dichotomy originally refers to the dispute between supporters (right) and opponents (left) of feudalism, so it cannot be validly extrapolated to anythihing older than feudalism. Spartakus or Tiberius Gracchus weren't leftists. Left and Right as we understand (though quite often we try to misunderstand rather than understand) them aren't metaphysical principles; they are purely historical realities, utterly dependent of the development of the actual forces of society.

The terms were invented by supporters of an absolutist monarchy, so unsurprisingly they used the term "right" to describe themselves, and "left" to describe their enemies. There are only two sides of our bodies, relative to the antero-posterior plane, left and right, and it stands to reason that when two humans face each other - as the president of an assembly regarding the ordinary members - that the left side of one corresponds to the right side of the other. So if the friends of the president stand to his right, he may call them the "right" of the assembly, taking himself as a standard. If they sit to his left, on the other hand, he might also call them the "right" of the assembly, now taking the benches as the standard. So, whatever the actual topographic position of supporters and opponents, the political "right" can call itself the right side, with all ideological load that this carries.

The "political compass" seems to be an instrument of political propaganda for the Libertarian Party, US. It attempts to frame political positions in a way that the best aspects of each "left" (ie, the Democrats, which in most of the world would be considered centrists at most) and "right" (ie, the Republicans) seem to match the Libertarian policies. It ignores the brutal fact that no serious political force embraces such apparently obviously excellent positions - which is probably best explained by the fact that the "best" aspects of what they call "left" are intimately intertwinned with what they consider the "worst" of that same left, and do not mingle well with what they consider the "best" aspects of what they call "right". Indeed, there is no reason why the political field should be bidimensional instead of uni- or tridimensional, nor is there any reason why, even if we agree that it is bidimensional, that it should take the form of a perfect square instead of an elongated rombus or rectangle.

The quote you give from the Dao De Jing doesn't seem to be about politics at all. It seems to describe complementary, not opposite, aspects of life.

---

ETA: an alternative - and less apologetic of conservatives - terminology from the same period, called the "left" "mountain" (for its members sat in the backbenches, which are in a higher position in an amphitheatre-like chamber) and the "right" "swamp".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The Dao De Jing is also about politics. To tell a sovereign not to use his army is a political counsel. And there's a continuum between "complementary" and "opposite", mostly when the DDJ agrees so strongly with today's use of political left/right. What you call "metaphysical principles" may just be some science you still don't know. Like biology. For instance, much of what Schopenhauer wrote in "Metaphysics of Love" became demonstrated by ethologists and evolutionary psychologists.

Comment: Maybe you'll like this article: http://www.thehindu.com/sci-tech/science/How-left-right-politics-affects-human-evolution/article16715391.ece. If the alpha male, in so many animal groups, eats the best piece and get laid with the best females, then to raise the power of the alpha male and his allies is what we call right-wing-politics. To lower the power of the alpha male and his allies, so that the lower ranking individuals can get a slightly better share -- that's the so-called left-wing-politics (*Pan troglodytes* is the "right-wing chimpanzee", *Pan paniscus* the "left-wing").

Comment: And this ever existing opposites -- which sometimes complement each other (mostly in the reign of an enlightened despot, or an enlightened taoist sovereign), other times declare war -- this opposites look so deeply built into our DNA, that anyone who thinks "biology is too easy" will probably call it "metaphysical".

Comment: @Rodrigo - I never said that the Dao De Jing isn't about politics. I said that the precise quote you gave seems to be not about politics, and it definitely does not counsel the sovereign on what to do with his army.

Comment: @Rodrigo - And these absurds about alpha-males are pseudo-science at best, and right-wing ideology at worst.

Comment: Of course the precise quote I gave does counsel the sovereign on what to do with his army. Maybe you'll have to read both chapters 30 and 31 to get the whole picture. Alpha-male "pseudo-science"? Do you know anything about zoology? In human politics, right-wing means helping the alpha-male (and alpha-female), when who needs help are the others.

Answer (score 0):

The first known "Political Parties" or "factions" as they were first termed that I am aware of were noted during the ratfication of the US Constitution. "Federalist" Party members were pro Constitution and "anti-Federalist" were against...and this was noted with some alarm during the ratification process as "office seeking" was seen as ungentlemanly. In other words one should asked first before one "becomes President" for example. Alexander Hamilton is the first and only proponent of "ambition" as the pre-requisite for Governing...meaning "do not ask but take." He actually wanted George Washington to be elected President for life in his only appearance before the Constitutional Committee meeting...in secret interestingly...in Philadelphia in 1789. This idea was never considered...but certainly Hamilton's "men of ambition" future was born out...and with it poltical parties.